# Trouble generating Java cores on Windows 7

Tags: java, multithreading

I have run into a situation where my Java process is hung. I ran my junit tcases's via eclipse which in turn starts another process which is hung.

Is there a way I generate Java cores from the hung process as ctrl-brk will not help me in this case as I dnt have the console.

I tried searching some options like jstack which won't help me as I am using IBM jvm,
SendSignal is not working on 64bit and stacktrace from adapatj is no longer available. I tried jconsole as well but when I try to select the process id it just keeps on trying connecting to the given process.

All I know is the process id of the Java process which is hung and I need Java cores to analyze why that process is in hung state.

Answer (score 0):

For `IBM JVMs` there is a section mentioned on  how to acquire the heap dumps here :
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Ftasks%2Facquiringheapdump.html

> **System Dumps and Heap Dumps from IBM Virtual Machines**
>
> Memory Analyzer can also read memory-related information from IBM
>   system dumps and from Portable Heap Dump (PHD) files.
>
> For this purpose
>   one just has to install the IBM DTFJ feature into Memory Analyzer
>   version 0.8 or later.
>
> Follow the IBM DTFJ feature installation
>   instructions.
>    If the DTFJ feature is successfully installed then File > Open Heap Dump menu should also offer the following options for the file types:
>   - IBM DTFJ for 1.4.2 VMs
>   - IBM DTFJ for Portable Heap Dumps
>   - IBM SDK for Java (J9) Javadump
>   - IBM SDK for Java (J9) System dumps
>
> Minimum-required versions of IBM Virtual Machines to generate the dump
>   are IBM JDK 1.4.2 SR12, 5.0 SR8a and 6.0 SR2 though previous versions
>   may generate dumps usable with Memory Analyzer but with inaccurate
>   root information

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Debug" view of Eclipse, select the hung process, right-click, choose "Properties", and you'll have the command used by eclipse to start the process. Launch this command in a console, and hit Ctrl-Break.